# How can prime factor of $q-1$ divide prime $q$?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, factoring

In this paper - "[A Subexponential Algorithm for the Discrete Logarithm Problem](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=4568001)", author mentions (page 56),

> For each $p_l^{e_l} | q$ proceed....

$p_l^{e_l}$  is one of the prime factors of $q-1$, and $q$ is a prime.

How can any number divide prime? Am I missing something here?

Edit1: $q$ is prime, so we can't get any non-trivial factor of $q$. Keeping this in mind, can anyone explain how to proceed with the steps mentioned in the paper. One thing to keep in mind is that $q$ has to be prime to be used in Diffie-Hellman system.

Comment: Presumably it's a typo and $q-1$ is meant, not $q$.

Comment: @fkraiem. Can you direct me to any source that says that it's a typo?

Answer (score 2):

For arbitrary positive integer $n$ we have:

> $$\gcd(n,n+1)=1$$

So $q-1$ and $q$ haven't any nontrivial common factor.

Answer (score 1):

It probably divides $q-1$ (composite) not $q$.